# Protect against vanishing output redirection targets

Tags: pipe, fifo, serial-console, busybox-init

I have a daemon running on an embedded Linux device with its output redirected to the serial console:

```bash
my_daemon > /dev/ttyS0
```

But now if a user `exit`s the shell running on the serial interface then the serial device gets recreated, which causes the serial device to temporary vanish and therefore causes my daemon to break.

Would there be some (straightforward) way to prevent this from happening? Perhaps some wrapper (or named pipe in combination with a process) in-between which retries to reconnect to the pipe target once it is gone? Buffering for that "offline" time is not needed.

Comment: Nothing should be deleting device files, so in the interest of understanding: 
- if you run `strace` on "my_daemon", what error/result is actually causing the exit? 
- could anything be generating a SIGHUP, so might `nohup` help?

Comment: @AndreBeaud `nohup` or `setpgrp` do not help. From how I understand it, it's that when you enter `exit` then the process gets restarted per what is written in `inittab` file (mind you it's a Busybox-based system) which then causes this behaviour.

Comment: (1) Is it acceptable that some bytes from the output of `my_daemon` are discarded when `/dev/ttyS0` vanishes? (2) In case `/dev/ttyS0` is not recreated for "long" time and `my_daemon` tries to write, should it (a) exit? (b) block? (c) be able to write anyway (but what it writes should be discarded)?

Comment: Would you get some line of the kind **ttyS0::respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS0 9600 vt100** in your inittab ? Did you try **not** specifying the <id> field ( **::respawn:/sbin/getty -L blahblah** ) ? (removing the leading ttyS0 I  mean)

Comment: Add this to all the others ways that logging via redirected stderr/stdout is a bad idea and even worse design: your supposed-to-be-long-lived-and-reliable process becomes inextricably tied to a single resource.

Comment: @AndrewHenle : I wholeheartedly support your statement.… added to the list of the reasons why I'll never run systemd.

Comment: @MC68020 Indeed.  Breaking `syslog` so it starts dropping log messages when systemd decides for some asinine reason that it gets "too many" is probably the greatest sin of systemd - other than its fundamental flaw of being a brain-dead, horribly-implemented, unreliable solution in search of a problem in the first place.

Comment: @MC68020 A binary is referenced there, perhaps it runs `getty` internally, I could try leaving out the `<id>` id field but I am afraid of breaking things.

Comment: The id field for busybox' inittab is particular. You can always omit it. If it is omitted then init's stdout will be used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following shell function:

```bash
relay () (
#!/bin/sh
sink="${1:-/dev/ttyS0}"
exec 4<&0 2>/dev/null
while :; do
   cat 3<"$sink" >/proc/self/fd/3
   <&4 cat >/dev/null & sleep 2; kill -s PIPE "$!" || exit
done
)
```

like this:

```
my_daemon | relay
```

What looks like a shebang (`#!/bin/sh`) means nothing inside the function. It's just an indication what shell the code is for. If you want to build a script, not a function, save the body of the function in an executable file and then the shebang will matter.

There are few tricks:

1. Solutions that use `cat >/dev/ttyS0` or similar redirection are potentially flawed. I assume your words "the serial device gets recreated" mean there is a time window when `/dev/ttyS0` does not exist. I also assume the user running the code (possibly root) may be able to create files in `/dev/`. If `>/dev/ttyS0` happens when there is no such file, a regular file will be created. You can test like `! [ -e /dev/ttyS0 ]`, but the file may disappear after the test and before `>/dev/ttyS0`.

   For this reason I use `cat 3<"$sink" >/proc/self/fd/3`, where `$sink` is `/dev/ttyS0` by default. The first redirection tries to open the file for reading; the second redirection tries to redirect stdout to the same file. The trick is the second redirection never creates a new file.

   An alternative would be to arrange things, so the user has access to `/dev/ttyS0`, but cannot create files in `/dev/`. In this case the trick would not be needed and solutions using `>/dev/ttyS0` should be safe. It may be a valid approach if you cannot use `/proc/self/fd/3` for whatever reason. The first `cat` would be just:

   ```
   cat >"$sink"
   ```
2. The purpose of the first cat is to send data to the sink. The redirections may fail or the sink may disappear eventually. Here comes the second `cat`. The purpose of the second `cat` is to discard data when there is no sink. If `/dev/ttyS0` should be recreated immediately, we wouldn't need the second `cat`. But I'm not sure if the pathname is guaranteed to reappear very fast in your case. I guess when there is no `/dev/ttyS0`, you want `my_daemon` to continue rather than [to block](https://superuser.com/q/1740428/432690). The second `cat` lets it continue.

   A simple `cat >/dev/null` is not a good idea, it could run indefinitely even after `/dev/ttyS0` gets recreated. The trick is to run it asynchronously and kill it after few seconds. Then the code loops and the first `cat` tries to open the sink again.

   `<&4` is needed because of the trick. When job control is disabled (and it is by default in a subshell our function is, or in a script), commands terminated with `&` get their stdin redirected to `/dev/null` or an equivalent file. Thanks to prior `exec 4<&0` and this `<&4`, the second `cat` can read from the stdin of the function anyway.
3. `kill` will (most likely) fail if the second `cat` is no more after `sleep 2`. This will happen if `my_daemon` exits. `kill … || exit` is a trick to detect EOF condition. E.g. `date | relay` should terminate, although after some delay because of `sleep`. Without the trick the code would loop indefinitely.

   In case of EOF it may happen the PID of the second `cat` gets reused and `kill` targets the wrong process. AFAIK in Linux PIDs are allocated sequentially; it's unlikely the sequence wraps around and gets to the same PID in about two seconds. The trick assumes that if the second `cat` exits early because of EOF, `kill` will see `no such process` and fail, thus `exit` will happen.

The default `$sink` is `/dev/ttyS0`, still you can use another pathname by specifying it as the first command line argument (e.g. `… | relay foo`). If you want to test on a regular file, remember that removing a file when it's open [does not destroy it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146929/108618). In my tests I used `set -x` to see what happens and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> [to easily terminate (the first) `cat` on demand](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/701317/108618).

My testbed: Linux kernel 5.15.0, `sh` (`ash`) from Busybox 1.30.1.

Comment: Your solution appears to work well. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

bufferpaster.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

while true;do
  cat buffer_file > /dev/ttyS0
done
```

and then run this:

```
my_daemon > buffer_file
./bufferpaster.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, in the absence of `strace` info then sure we can check/wait for a valid device file. Assuming that the daemon outputs lines ending on newlines (for the `read`), then maybe something like this:

```
tty=/dev/ttyS0
my_daemon | ( 
    # Start with a read of 1 line, to catch when the daemon exits, and then "cat" the rest
    while read line; do 
        # check/wait for device file to exist and be writable
        until [ -w $tty ]; do sleep 1; done
        echo "$line"  >> $tty
        cat >> $tty
    done
)
```

The `>>` appends are in case you want to test to a file first, instead of to `ttyS0`

Answer (score 0):

Write the stdout to a log file, and then have your initsystem inittab/systemd just tail -F  the log file to the serial port.  Init will take care of ensuring that the tail is running on the serial port, and you can focus on writing your daemon.  you will need to put in a log rotation, but there are utilities you can use for that (like piper, multilog, there is a whole discussion of how to create log files here by pipeing stdout: https://superuser.com/questions/291368/log-rotation-of-stdout )

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski  no, we just want the tail to die from SIGHUP, but the init manager will respawn it.  that's how getty works, every time you logout either init or systemd just respawns it as specified in the config file.

Comment: OK, I get it now.